# Inconsistent behavior when tabbing through pages containing sifr

Tags: internet-explorer, sifr

I've noticed inconsistent behavior when I try to tab through links on web pages that have implemented sifr 2.0.7. In IE7, I cannot successfully tab through an entire page. Tabbing seems to stop on the first link that follows an sifr element. I've removed all CSS (except that which is required for sifr) and still experience the same issue. Any remedies? Anyone else experience the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer (7 & 8) both seem to have inconsistent behavior in tabbing through links.  I've got a keyboard accessible menu that I'm building with jQuery and CSS, and while every other browser (and IE9) browse sequentially through all nested lists, IE gives up tabbing through the links when it hits the second nested list and returns to the start of the links — completely disregarding the rest of the links on the page.

While I don't have a solution for you, I'm led to believe that it's not exclusively an sifr issue, and has something more to do with IE and its interpretation of any changes in the DOM.  IE chokes when I have jQuery display a new set of links (that are in the DOM but just have a change in display: value) and just refuses to keep dialing through the DOM.

Not sure what to say, but I'm on the same quest as you for answers.